# Animating a rotating pie slice in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation

I'm trying to create a rotating radar type effect in Photoshop CC 2018. So I created a circle and a pie slice from that circle and linked them up. When I rotate the big circle the pie slice animates like an independent object rather than part of a circular rotation.

[image: A pie slice rotating jerkily inside a circle]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of linking the slice to the circle and animating the circle, try grouping the circle and the pie slice and animating the entire group. This should fix everything.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried a group, but I quickly noticed that groups don't take key frames. I don't know why I didn't think to make the group a Smart Object. [A final rotating radar type effect](https://i.imgur.com/jSOlQ1G.gif)